# Solving Laplace Transform of $-e^{-at}u(-t)$

Tags: integration, exponential-function

I have found a problem in applying Laplace Transform to $-e^{-at}u(-t)$
I am doing these steps:

$$ = - \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-at}u(-t)  e^{-st}dt$$
$$ = - \int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{-at}  e^{-st}dt$$
$$ = - \int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{-(a+s)t}dt$$
$$ = - [-\frac{1}{a+s} e^{-(a+s)t}]|_{-\infty}^{0}$$
$$ = - [-\frac{1}{a+s} (e^{-(a+s)0}-e^{-(a+s)-\infty})]$$

$$ = - [-\frac{1}{a+s} (1- \infty)]$$

$$ = \infty$$
Can anyone help me why it is showing like that.I check it on internet and all the books are showing the answer is $\frac{1}{s+a}$

Comment: What is $u(-t)$? Is it supposed to be the Heaviside function?

Comment: I am not sure about Heaviside function. but in the book it is mentioned like that $u(-t)$

Comment: do we need to do any assumption? like $k=-t$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually Laplace transform is defined as 
$$\mathcal{L} f=
\int_{0}^{+\infty} f(t)  e^{-st}dt
$$
The transform 
$${\mathcal{B}} f=
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(t)  e^{-st}dt
$$
is a bilateral Laplace transform.

For a Laplace transform $\mathcal{L} e^{at}f = F(s-a)$ where $F=\mathcal{L} f$, i.e. a frequency shifting. 
Similarly $\mathcal{L} e^{-at}f = F(s+a)$

Now, you talking about $u(-t)$. As I could guess from your integration and since this is a pretty common notation for a Laplace transform discussion, $u(t)$ is a step function, also called [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).

Now, $\mathcal{L} u(t)=\frac{1}{s}$, therefore $\mathcal{L} (e^{-at}u(t))=\frac{1}{s+a}$. However, $\mathcal{L} u(-t) = 0$.

**Note**

In your integration you get (note that you assume $s+a\ne 0$. The $s+a=0$ is a special case which should give $\infty$)

$$\frac{1}{a+s}e^{-(a+s)t} \Bigg|_{-\infty}^0
=\frac{1}{a+s}\left(e^0-\lim_{r\to\infty} e^{(a+s)r}\right)
=\begin{cases}
\infty &a+s>0\\
\frac{1}{a+s}&a+s<0
\end{cases}
$$
since
$$\lim_{r\to\infty} e^{-(a+s)r} = \begin{cases}
\infty &a+s>0\\
0&a+s<0
\end{cases}$$

Comment: so do you mean my way doing integration is wrong? how can I proof it like I saw in literature

Comment: I mean that either, you interesting in Bilateral Laplace Transform or you use a wrong formula for Laplace transform.

Comment: still not clear, does it mean if I use bilateral Laplace Transform than it should be same like literature? the second option of using wrong formula is not correct because same thing is used in Signals and System by Alan Oppenheim

Comment: You integration is fine when $Re(a+s)\ge0$ otherwise you will get the same $\frac{1}{s+a}$

Comment: but I am getting $\infty$ not $\frac{1}{s+a}$

Comment: This is because you implicitly assumed that $a+s>0$ (they supposed to be reals, so I omit the $Re$).

Comment: I think when I applied the limits that makes the function to $\infty$

Comment: Can you please write it as answer of what you think is write

Comment: please note the edit

Comment: in the final equation you mean that it will either $\infty$ or 0? not $\frac{1}{s+a}$?

Comment: the "final equation" explains the previous one, i.e. the one you need

Comment: Usually when we apply the integral upper and lower bounds we don't write it in limit form.. secondly if we write it in the form of limit than it will no more depend on $t$? as you wrote the cases for $a+s>0$ and $a+s<0$

Comment: can you show where did you find $t$ in the limit?